# Animate an element to the size of screen in fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

How do I animate a `<div>` to expand to fit the screen upon clicking. All while staying in fixed position, then revealing the contents of that `<div>`

Image:

[image: sample]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Set a CSS3 `transition` to your element.
2. Create a **class** that makes your element `100vw` and `100vh` (viewport width height units)
3. **Add that class** on click

```js
$("#box").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("fullScreen");
});
```

```css
html, body{height:100%;margin:0;}

/* YOUR BOX */
#box{
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden; /* in order to contain content */
  
  /* The initial styles: */
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: red;
  left:50px; bottom:50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  

  /* TRANSITION TO THE RESCUE */
          transition: 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
}

/* ADD THIS CLASS WITH JS */
#box.fullScreen{
  /* Your override styles: */
  border-radius: 0;
  background: gold;
  left:0; bottom:0;
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">CLICK</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `transform: scale(  )` to scale the full screen box proportionally down and up. Scaling also affects the content of the box. The small version of the box then has the same aspect ratio as the full screen box.

### Example

```js
$("#box").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("fullScreen");
});
```

```css
html, body{height:100%;margin:0;}

/* YOUR BOX */
#box{
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  
  /* make the box full screen */
  width: 100vw; /* IE9+ */
  height:100vh; /* IE9+ */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  /* scale it down to 0.1 (10%) initially,
     make an offset from bottom left */
  -ms-transform: translate(50px, -50px) scale(0.1); /* IE9 */
  -ms-transform-origin: left bottom; /* IE9 */
  transform: translate(50px, -50px) scale(0.1);
  transform-origin: left bottom;

  /* smooth transition (IE10+) */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
          transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

/* ADD THIS CLASS WITH JS */
#box.fullScreen {
  /* Your override style:
     remove offset, scale it to 1 (100%) */
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1); /* IE9 */
  transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>click the box</div>
<div id="box">your content</div>
```

Comment: While this is a great answer, the problem is you cannot specify a specific width and height to the `#box` and its size will vary depending on the screen size