# Animate overlay from origin relative to an element

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to animate an overlay to expand to fullscreen from the UI element that triggers the overlay. For instance, I have a button that when clicked shows an overlay, I would like the overlay to expand from the button (either above or below the button, not important at this point).

I am using something similar to the second answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37687014/animate-an-element-to-the-size-of-screen-in-fixed-position#answer-37690376) at the moment. The issue is that the `position: fixed` rule removes the overlay(`#box` in the example) from the document flow and therefore the positioning is relative to the entire document.

So I guess the question is, can the flow be maintained, or relative positioning used to achieve the desired result? At the moment the only solution I can think of is using JS to set the `transform: translate` positioning appropriately upon load and resize to match the button location. I'd love if there was a more elegant way to achieve this.

**Edit:** The below code is almost verbatim yanked from the above question, I'd like to add a `button` or similar interaction element having the animation originate relatively from it's location and not the viewport.

```js
document.getElementById('box').addEventListener('click', (e) => e.target.classList.toggle('fullscreen'));
```

```css
    #box {
        position: fixed;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: red;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform: translate(50px, -50px) scale(0.1);
        transform-origin: left bottom;
        transition: all 0.7s ease;
    }

    #box.fullscreen {
          transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);
    }
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

**Edit:** Thinking about it a bit more, an animated background change, like a `radial-gradient` might do the trick also, I'd just have to hide elements until the animation completes, but it may be an option. The animation origin to fullscreen effect is the important part. Will update if I make any solid progress in the meantime. Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you post what you have done and what is the problem. Im not understanding the problem really. so you want the overlay to begin from the button then spread to the whole screen(even over the button) ? is that so ? if so is it ok to use jq

Comment: Hi @Alen.Toma ! Thanks for the reply. What I have so far is exactly the code in the [answer linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37687014/animate-an-element-to-the-size-of-screen-in-fixed-position#answer-37690376), just with the colour and initial dimensions modified. The only difference is that I want to position the `#box` relative to another element and not the viewport. Yup, using JS (or jQ) is not a problem, as I mentioned above with respect to the calculation of the transform. I'm totally open to suggestion. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i made some changes and it should work as you wished. Make sure to read the comment so you understand the idee.

```js
$(".expand").on("click", function() {
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  var box = $("#box");
  // make sure that the position of the overlay start from the clicked element
  box.css({ left:rect.left , top: rect.top + rect.height }); 
   
  box.toggleClass("fullScreen").delay(500).queue(function() {
    box.css({ left:0 , top: 0 }); // the toggle finished then reset the left and top so it overlay the whole screen 
  });

});
```

```css
/* YOUR BOX */
#box{
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  /* make the box full screen */
  /* scale it down to 0.1 (10%) initially,
     make an offset from bottom left */
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(0.1); /* IE9 */
  -ms-transform-origin: left top; /* IE9 */
  transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(0.1);
  transform-origin: left top;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  /* smooth transition (IE10+) */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
          transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

/* ADD THIS CLASS WITH JS */
#box.fullScreen {
  width: 100vw; /* IE9+ */
  height:100vh; /* IE9+ */
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1); /* IE9 */
  transform: translate(0px, 0px) scale(1);
}

.expand{

margin:auto;
width:100px;


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expand">Click Me</div>


<div id="box">your content</div>
```

Comment: Hi again @Alen.Toma ! I wanted to wait a little while before accepting your answer to see if a CSS only solution was submitted/possible. Your solution works perfectly though! :+1: In the end I opted to create/modify a custom selector with a transform, that's just personal preference though. Many thanks for taking the time! webstudent

Comment: Np, glad i could help